# Is parsing an ini file in PHP better than having variables defined in code?

Tags: php, security, file-io, ini

I was reading about PDO and I came across the parse_ini_file function. A number of developers suggested using this function to parse in db settings rather than hard coding the db settings in code for security reasons.

My question to you is, does it make sense to do a file read for every load of your PHP application for this extra "security" ?

I wonder how expensive this file read is..

php 5.3
in the comments 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel "Lamers"? Is it still the 1980's? Is my Amiga better than your ST? ;-)

Comment: @codeninja: Could you please link to this source? I honestly can't say I've heard/read anything about something like that being _good_ for security, in fact it sounds patently stupid...but I like to keep an open mind and would be interested in reading about it myself. ;-)

Comment: yes, there are always lots of people, who have no idea of what are they talking about, no matter it's 1080s, 1980s or 2080s

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel. Maybe that's why they turn to stackoverflow. They realise they are not sure of something (or as you put it "have no idea what they are talking about"). So they come somewhere where some friendly people will give them some advice!

Comment: @tjm friendly but utterly unexperienced. That's THE problem.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel Yeah. Do you think your attitude helps with the learning process? :-)

Comment: @middaparka sometimes. But sometimes it's just a despair.

Comment: Oh, and @middaparka. The ST was WAY better!

Comment: @middaparka take this concern of "how expensive this file read is" for example. Performance concerns are extremely popular. But none ever try to think, how many files being read by the server to serve just one webpage. People just repeat wild rumors after each other. None of them have experience (including ones who answer) but only some set of "advises" they have read somewhere.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel. Sorry, I'd told myself I was going to leave this alone and I know that last comment wasn't directed to me, but, the questioner clearly says "I wonder how expensive this file read is..". The fact he/she is *asking* the question, and the *"I wonder"* give away that they *are* thinking about this. They just want it clarified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't really see how it's any more secure.

For example, if your DB settings are stored in defines within a "config.php" file **outside of the main web root**, they're just as secure as if they're were stored in a .ini file and there would be no per-page parsing overhead (other than having to include the config file as per normal).

Comment: The advantage of the ini file is that you can grant access to somebody who you don't trust writing PHP code. It's a small thing, but in some environments that might be meaningful.

Comment: @konforce - A valid point. That said, I'm not sure I'd want someone who doesn't know PHP messing around with database settings and anyone who understands the significance of such things could trivially change a define.

Comment: @konforce someone who has full DB access but have no rights to the PHP code? Funny tale.

Comment: There may be a settings folder that certain administrative people have FTP access to. People store more than DB credentials in settings files. If their account gets compromised, do you really want people to be able to inject arbitrary code into the site? It's not so funny... I've seen it happen.

Comment: @konforce Straying somewhat from the .ini vs .php context, but very true. :-)

Comment: @konforce your imagination is magnificent. It's pity that real life is way simpler than you imagine. What about **HTTP access** to set settings?

Answer (score 1):

Hard coding settings in PHP files is bad because those same PHP files will be sent around, copied, put into repositories, etc. The passwords should be treated with more privacy. Also, it's annoying to have to the source files overwrite your local copies.

Note that I'm referring specifically to embedding in regular PHP files in your project's codebase. If you place your config settings in a PHP file that sits external to all of that, then none of the above applies.

If you are worried about the overhead of parsing one config file, then you shouldn't be using PHP at all... However, you could limit file reads by parsing it only when a cached (e.g., memcache) copy cannot be found.

Comment: How would the .ini file be any different? They're still likely to be sent around, etc. (Or am I missing something?)

Comment: @middaparka, I clarified my answer. I'm speaking specifically of embedding configuration within the application code/respository. My point isn't INI vs PHP, but internal vs external.

Comment: Yup, have to agree. No idea why your answer was downvoted. (Seems a bit extreme.)

Comment: database settings being moved into repositories as well.

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense if you have more than just db access stored in the ini file . It can act like a config for you're app so you don't have to open 10 files to change 3 hardcoded variables/constants/whatever . If you don't like reading a file each time you're app is requested then use a php file to store all you're config options ( keep them all in one place is realy good ) , and as sugested keep the ini/php config file out of you're web root .

Answer (score 1):

Probably not.  If its a .ini file then a browser can just visit it and download it.  At least a .php has a decency of a blank screen.